# ora-01410 invalid RowID sporadically in a select statement

Tags: oracle-10g, select, corruption

I have a select that looks up some data by a join. The system runs Oracle 10.02g and the select looks like this

```
SELECT distinct t1.crit
  FROM table_name1 t1
 INNER JOIN table_name2 t2
    ON t1.crit = t2.crit
 WHERE NVL (t2.qty, 0) + NVL (t2.adds, 0) - NVL (t2.remove, 0) > 0
   AND t1.process_id = 'some_process_id'
   AND t1.item_no = 'some item NO'
   AND t1.to_gen = 1
```

where t1 has an index on (item_no, crit), and t2 has an index on (item_no, crit, X), and X is some additional column.

The objective of this statement is to find all candidates for which I need to generate data in additional tables. When the new data has been generated, the column t1.to_gen is set to 0. At the moment it is not clear, if the software which runs this statement, does intermediate commits, e.g. generates some new data for one item_no, sets t1.to_gen = 0 and commits, before using the next item_no from the cursor of the statement in question.

This statement is executed successfully several times a day in my environment, but in rare cases I get an error from oracle, whose source is not clear to me:

```
ora-01410: invalid RowID
```

As the select statement does not use the pseudo-column RowID direcly, Oracle will have to use it internally.

What is the source of this problem?

**Update:** Sad as it sounds, the system does intermediate commits, but that is not the source of the problem.

Comment: Are you sure the error is produced by the `SELECT` and not some other statement in your code?

Comment: Are you issuing commits and continuing to use your cursor after doing so? That's a very bad habit.

Comment: @ypercube: yes I am sure, our exception handling writes the error code and the causing statement into a log-file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are there other processes operating on the same tables? Indexes being rebuilt?

If so, then you could be hitting the situation that Jonathan Lewis describes here: https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2007/09/16/index-rebuild/

> Consider this: if you rebuild an index (whether or not you use the ***online*** option) Oracle will copy the index contents from one location to another and, when the copy is complete, free up the space that held the original index contents.
>
> What’s going to happen to a long running query that started running before you did your rebuild? Surprisingly the query will carry on running using the “old” index. Oracle introduced a form of ‘*cross-DDL read consistency*’ many years ago to make ***partition maintenance operations*** possible, and that’s the feature that allows your query to carry on running.
>
> But what’s going to happen if some other process now demands the space and puts something into it – for example by creating or extending a table or index. The next time your long-running query hits the “old” index it may find itself looking at a block that contains the wrong type of data for the wrong object id. And so you get Oracle error ***ORA-01410: invalid rowid***.

Comment: That's it! The system started an index rebuild while the select statement ran.